# Azure Devops : unauthorized: authentication required,

Tags: azure, azure-devops, containers, registry, pipeline

need some help. I created a custom image that pushes to Azure Container Registry and use it as a based image for the Azure DevOps pipeline, but it seems it does not pull the image.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
jobs:
- job: rf
  container:
    image: test.net/rethrf:8944
```

**Output**

```
Error response from daemon: Head "https://test.net/v2/rethrf/manifests/8944": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
##[warning]Docker pull failed with exit code 1, back off 2.89 seconds before retry.
```

any solution to this? or did I miss any environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you need to add a service connection since you are communicating with the other azure services.
- you can add service connection in portal it is under the project settings.
  [image]

[image]

- Select service connection and after that popup will appear on which you have to select docker registry
  [image]
- Fill the subsequent form about the subscription and ACR details
  [image]
- Another approach would be to use docker to pull images

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli#pull-the-image-from-your-registry) about it.